# Crawling Password Protected Popup Sites

Tags: javascript, perl, web-crawler, bots

There is a website that I am trying to crawl,

Comment: It is likely HTTP basic authentication.  You just need to send the authentication credentials along with the request.

Comment: In case you're using something like `WWW::Mechanize` and the page depends on JavaScript for the popup, keep in mind `WWW::Mechanize` doesn't support it...

Comment: @darkajax: In 99% of the cases the form will just be unhidden by JavaScript, so you can still fill it out without JS.

Comment: @AlexanderChristiansson maybe, of course this still could have been part of the "1%" where the form is generated on-the-fly via JavaScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The popup is probably standard HTTP auth. If that is the case, you can send credentials like this:

```
http://user:pass@example.com
```